# Unable to get value of the property 'options': object is null or undefined using jquery fileupload

Tags: jquery, file-upload

I am woriking on jQuery fileupload. I had tried in my HTML page it's working fine and great. When I am calling same page in popup I am getting an error. I am using modal popup.

```
add: function(e, data) {

    var that = $(this).data('fileupload'),
        options = that.options,
        files = data.files;

    that._adjustMaxNumberOfFiles(-files.length);
    data.isAdjusted = true;

    $(this).fileupload('resize', data).done(data, function() {
        data.files.valid = data.isValidated = that._validate(files);
        data.context = that._renderUpload(files)
            .appendTo(options.filesContainer)
            .data('data', data);
        that._renderPreviews(files, data.context);
        that._forceReflow(data.context);
        that._transition(data.context).done(function() {
            if ((that._trigger('added', e, data) !== false) && (options.autoUpload || data.autoUpload) && data.autoUpload !== false && data.isValidated) {
                data.submit();
            }
        });
    });
},
```

When I am uploading the image it is saying that:

```
0x800a138f - Microsoft JScript runtime error:
Unable to get value of the property 'options': object is null or undefined
```

I did't get the idea how to solve and how to find the way for this. I am getting error only if I call it in popup. Do you have any solution? Find it out plz, help. How to get the value?

Comment: *I am getting error only if I call it in popup* you are loosing context in this case, so the line `this` in here `$(this).data('fileupload')` is not what you  expect. Show how you call `add` method.